# Arrow functions within classes are not supported in chrome but work fine through babel, why?

Tags: google-chrome, ecmascript-6, babeljs, arrow-functions

The correct syntax for writing arrow functions within a class should be

```
greet = () => {console.log('greet')}
```

While this compiles fine in Babel (using es2015 default) the chrome devtools throws an error.

This confuses me, as according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions they are completely supported in Chrome.

Is this a non-standard syntax? If so, why is it supported in Babel. If not, where can I see the support status

Comment: *Which* error does it throw? (Btw, it works just fine for me)

Comment: Wait, "*writing arrow functions within a class*" - you cannot put arrow functions (or any other assignments) in a `class` body (not in Chrome and not in ES6 Babel either), if that is what you refer to; please post the complete code. Property assignments belong inside the constructor.

Comment: Also, please show some surrounding context as "within classes" is not fully descriptive of where this code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the [**class fields** proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields):

> **Field declarations**
>
> With the ESnext field declarations proposal, the above example can be written as
>
> ```
> class Counter extends HTMLElement {
>   x = 0;
>
>   clicked() {
>     this.x++;
>     window.requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
>   }
>
>   constructor() {
>     super();
>     this.onclick = this.clicked.bind(this);
>   }
>
>   connectedCallback() { this.render(); }
>
>   render() {
>     this.textContent = this.x.toString();
>   }
> }
> window.customElements.define('num-counter', Counter);
> ```
>
> In the above example, you can see a field declared with the syntax `x = 0`. You can also declare a field without an initializer as `x`. By declaring fields up-front, class definitions become more self-documenting; instances go through fewer state transitions, as declared fields are always present.

It's a stage 3 proposal and has nothing to do with arrow functions. Any value can be assigned to a field, including arrow functions.

---

> While this compiles fine in Babel (using es2015 default)

I'm sure other plugins are configured. Since this is a proposal and not part of ES2016, *only* enabling the ES2015 preset won't transform this syntax.